# How do I access the title of a Material App using stock Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am developing a widget that displays the current page's title without needing the title set directly. In the past, I have used Beamer's `context.currentBeamPages.last.title` to retrieve this however, we are migrating from `Beamer` to `GoRouter` and this hook is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the name property on the RouteSettings object for the current MaterialPageRoute.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteSettings/name.html

```
ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name;
```